# Callback as a post method

Tags: node.js, callback

I have a callback function as a post method :

```
app.post('/callback', function (req, res) {});
```

I am not able to return response value on the browser.
Can anybody post a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not handling it properly. See this example:

```
app.post('/callback', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('success')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.post('/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Im callback');
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this methods to return response from callback. These are the most common methods for sending response:

```
app.post('/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send('send any data');
  // or
  return res.sendFile('enter File path to send');
  // or  
  return res.json({toSend: 'json object'});
});
```

**Note**: that you can use only one of them, except with if-condition clause. The first one is run returns the response.

also see express document for other methods on `res`: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: I have tried printing res.Headers. It changes from false to true however i am still not seeing a response on the web browser

Comment: What is `res.Headers()`? Express don't have such method on `res`, use `res.send('OK!');` instead and you would see the `OK!` on your browser